# Stability analysis for differential inclussion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential, stability-in-odes

I have a differential inclusion of the form $\dot{x}\in F(x)$, with $F(x)$ a set valued function that is also upper hemicontinuous.

I want to analyze if a critical point of the system, $x^*$, such that $0 \in F(x^*)$ is locally saddle-path stable.

How do I do that?

By Hartman–Grobman theorem, we know that if $F(x)$ were a differentiable function, one could linearize around $x^*$ and look at the eigenvalues of the Jacobian. Is there a similar procedure that applies when $F(x)$ is set valued around $x^*$?